# How to open CRM entity record with Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm

I need to open crm record from selenium using c# ? now I navigated sales->Contacts.In the screen I can find contacts sub grid.

Now I need to open record from contact grid.How can I do this?

Comment: Where can we find `CRM entity Record`?

Comment: after clicked on Contacts button from sales then we can see contacts records in grid

Answer (score 0):

I believe your are talking about the Main grid(`crmGrid`) when you navigate to a `sub-area` like `Contacts` or `Accounts` in CRM.

We use the following `JavaScript` to access elements and open them in new tab. I `don't know the Selenium syntax` but you can modify it to your needs.

```
var selectedRecords = document.getElementById("crmGrid").control.get_selectedRecords();
  var rowscount = selectedRecords.length;
  if (rowscount >= 1) {
      var url = "/main.aspx?etc="; //etc=1;   //&id=";
      var tempurl = url;
     for (var i = 0; i < rowscount; i++) {
       tempurl = tempurl + selectedRecords[i].TypeCode + "&id=" + selectedRecords[i].Id + "&pagetype=entityrecord";
       window.open(tempurl);
       tempurl = null;
       tempurl = url;
        }
    }
```

**You can do something like :**

```
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();             
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.crm.crm");  
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("contentIFrame0");  //Switch to the main page of the Grid
var crmGrid = driver.FindElement(By.Id("crmGrid"));
var selectedRecords = document.getElementById("crmGrid").control.get_selectedRecords();
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRecords.length ; i++) {
   var eachRecord= selectedRecords[i]; 
 }
```

[Application of Selenium WebDriver for testing of MS Dynamics CRM](http://developers-club.com/posts/274001/)
[Selenium with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Automating Send Keys to Composite Fields](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2017/09/13/selenium-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-automating-send-keys-to-composite-fields)